# Which XSLT processor actually took advantage of parallel-processing?

Tags: xslt

XSLT processing has the potential to be very fast because many of it's *language elements* allows things to be processed in parallel.

However even though *theoretically* things can run in parallel and processing *can* be insanely fast, in practice is there an actual implementation of an XSLT processor that took advantage of this potential and actually run things in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have to look at the high-end commercial XSLT processors (Datapower, Intel) for this kind of capability. There's very little technical information available about either, but there have been one or two conference papers describing techniques that may or may not have found their way into product.

(Personally, I have a bit of a feeling that both these products sell on the basis that if the product is expensive, it must be good. But that feeling is based solely on the absence of information, rather than on any real knowledge.)

Comment: If this is the THE Michael Kay, can you confirm/deny what Saxon does provide in terms of multithreading? Is the EE-only for-each extension attribute referenced in @Martin Honnen's answer the only such feature?

Comment: Yes, there's the feature Honnen describes; also a very limited use of two threads to resolve push-pull conflicts when streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Saxon's documentation http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/attributes/threads.xml documents an extension attribute for `xsl:for-each` to specify the number of threads to be used to execute the for-each. It is only available in the commercial version of Saxon, I haven't used that so I can't tell you more about it.